# R lubridate: Apply helper to dataframe

Tags: r, lubridate

I have a dataframe of times looking like this:

```
library(lubridate)

times <- structure(list(exp1 = c("17:19:04 \r", "17:28:53 \r", "17:38:44 \r"), 
                        exp2 = c("17:22:04 \r", "17:31:53 \r", "17:41:45 \r")), 
                        row.names = c(NA, 3L), class = "data.frame")
```

I want to convert the times in more convenient date-time objects, which I will do with the `hms()` helper function from the `lubridate` package.

Running `hms()` on one column of my dataframe works like a charm:

```
hms(times[,1])
```

> [1] "17H 19M 4S"  "17H 28M 53S" "17H 38M 44S"

Great, surely I can just `apply()` on my whole dataframe then.

```
apply(times, 2, hms)
```

Which gives a weird dataframe with some integers, definitely not what I am expecting.

What is the right way to convert all of my `times` dataframe with the `hms()` function?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `apply`, can use `lapply` as `apply` converts to `matrix` and it wouln't hold the attributes created by `hms`

```
library(lubridate)
times[] <- lapply(times, hms)
str(times)
#'data.frame':  3 obs. of  2 variables:
# $ exp1:Formal class 'Period' [package "lubridate"] with 6 slots
#  .. ..@ .Data : num  4 53 44
#  .. ..@ year  : num  0 0 0
#  .. ..@ month : num  0 0 0
#  .. ..@ day   : num  0 0 0
#  .. ..@ hour  : num  17 17 17
#  .. ..@ minute: num  19 28 38
# $ exp2:Formal class 'Period' [package "lubridate"] with 6 slots
#  .. ..@ .Data : num  4 53 45
#  .. ..@ year  : num  0 0 0
#  .. ..@ month : num  0 0 0
#  .. ..@ day   : num  0 0 0
#  .. ..@ hour  : num  17 17 17
#  .. ..@ minute: num  22 31 41
```

---

With the `devel` version of `dplyr`, we can use `mutate` with `across`

```
library(dplyr)
times %>%
    mutate(across(everything(), hms))
```

Answer (score 2):

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

times %>% mutate_all(hms)
#OR
mutate_all(times, hms)
#         exp1        exp2
#1  17H 19M 4S  17H 22M 4S
#2 17H 28M 53S 17H 31M 53S
#3 17H 38M 44S 17H 41M 45S
```